# Regex: Match all quotes inside >< brackets (not inside <>)

Tags: regex

i have a text like this:

```
hi this is <some-tag parameter="abc"> example text with 
quote sign here " and also some quote sign here " and here ". 
Quote does not have to be closed. And some numbers here 123.
</some-tag>
```

Regex should match " " " (3 times ") in example above.

Basically, what i need is to match all occurrences of double quotes (**"**) that are surrounded by **>** and **<** brackets using regex expression.

Please not that I am not looking for tags or anything between <>, i am looking only for double quotes between ><, like this: > **"** <

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should show a minimal understanding of the problem by posting what have been tried, what was the expected results and what the problem was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with @Sammitch's suggestion (about using a parser). Still, referring to the sample you provided, you may try this:

```
(?<=>[\s\S-[<]]*?)"
```

And [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=37bc1e90-1f4e-400b-b166-8dbde3c257ba)'s a demo.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
preg_match_all('/<.*"([^"])".*>/', $text);
```

But not in a sane way that anyone would recommend using. Use an XML/HTML/DOM parser if you want actual sanity in your code.

Answer (score 0):

/<[^>]*=("[^>]*)">/
will get you your tags

This site may help you: http://www.phpliveregex.com/